# c++: static assert checking whether used const is in predefined list

Tags: c++, static-assert

how to solved this issue:

I have predefinded const list of integers:

```
const auto numbers = {1, 5, 10};
```

I want to use static_assert (compilation time) to check whether some other const value:

```
#define SOME_IDENTIFIER 1
```

is in the list. How would you do that? Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: const int numbers = {1, 5, 10}; this line itself is incorrect

Comment: typo const int numbers[] = {1, 5, 10};

Comment: Which language standard should be used here?

Comment: Off-topic: prefer a `constexpr` to a macro. Had to say it, and I'll be going now.

Comment: Fixed the typo. Couldn't resist. Sorry. Also forces C++11 and greater.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++2a:

```
constexpr std::array numbers{1, 5, 10};

constexpr int some_id = 1;
static_assert(std::any_of(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 
    [](const auto& x){ return x == some_id; }));
```

---

C++17:

```
template <typename C, typename X>
constexpr bool contains(const C& container, const X& x)
{
    for(const auto& elem : container) if(x == elem) return true;
    return false;
}

constexpr std::array numbers{1, 5, 10};

constexpr int some_id = 1;
static_assert(contains(numbers, some_id));
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XPYA0q8lbe2PWl83)

---

C++14:

```
constexpr int numbers[]{1, 5, 10};

constexpr int some_id = 1;
static_assert(contains(numbers, some_id));
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kblQ1KRvBj5Sjr2j)

---

C++11:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool contains_impl(std::size_t n, const T* arr, const T& x)
{
    return n != 0 && (arr[0] == x || contains_impl(n - 1, arr + 1, x));
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool contains(const T(&arr)[N], const T& x)
{
    return contains_impl<T>(N, &arr[0], x);
}
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zoamomBaqCizSdGn)

Comment: Unfortunately, `any_of` isn't constexpr until C++20. Not that it's hard to write one's own constexpr `contains` or something.

Comment: @chris: fixed! :)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - In record time, no less :P

Comment: C++11 version has infinite recursion if the element is not found.

Answer (score 2):

And, in C++11 with good old manual partial specialization (simplified version where `numbers` are global):

```
constexpr std::array<int,3> numbers = {1, 5, 10};

template <size_t I,int N>
struct check {
   static constexpr bool value = 
      (numbers[I] == N) || check<I-1,N>::value;
};

template <int N>
struct check<0,N> {
   static constexpr bool value = (numbers[0] == N);
};

constexpr int n = 1;
static_assert(check<numbers.size()-1,n>::value);
```

Comment: I added a C++11 solution as well :) - BTW I don't think `array::operator[]` is `constexpr` in C++11